# Quickly assign all the members of a base object to a derived object in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

Say we have one base class and one derived class:

```
class Base {
  string s1;
  string s2;
  ...
  string s100; // Hundreds of members
};

class Derived : public Base{
  string s101;
};
```

I want to assign a Base object `base` to a Derived object `derived`. I know we can't just use operator "=" to assign a base object to its derived object.
My question is: Do we have to make copies of all the members one by one? Like:

```
derived.s1 = base.s1;
derived.s2 = base.s2;
...
derived.s100 = base.s100;
```

Is there any faster or more concise way to do this? Overload an operator= with
the returned base object?

Comment: base = derived?

Comment: The derived object is not there and I only have a base object as a data source at the time. I want to create a new derived object, assign its members and put it in a container, say a map.

Comment: then why did you write 'base.s1 = derived.s1'

Comment: Assuming `Base` supports assignment to `Base`) and does NOT have an `operator=()` that accepts a `Derived`, then `base=derived` will work.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are asking about `base = derived;`, or `derived = base;`

Comment: You should look at the bigger picture. The fact your class has hundreds of members, is indicative of poor design. No class should have that many members, let alone one intended for subclassing. It's potentially placing a terrible burden on the subclasser. Can you roll them into a vector or an array. In fact do you have control over this class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to assign a Base object base to a Derived object derived.

Provide an overload `operator=` for it:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    Derived& operator=(const Base& b) { 
        Base::operator=(b); // call operator= of Base
        s101 = something;   // set sth to s101 if necessary
        return *this; 
    }
};
```

Then you can

```
Base b;
// ...
Derived d;
// ...
d = b;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know we can't just use operator "=" to assign a base object to its
>   derived object.

Of course you can (in the context of this question):

```
static_cast<Base &>(derived)=base;
```

Stock example:

```
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

void foo()
{
    Derived d;
    Base b;

    static_cast<Base &>(d)=b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this static_cast. However, is this a good practice, even in this situation?

Comment: @M.M - not according to gcc 6.1.1: "t.C:12:4: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Derived’ and ‘Base’)"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik fair enough

Answer (score 0):

> I know we can't just use operator "=" to assign a base object to its derived object

That's not true.

> Do we have to make copies of all the members one by one? Like:
>   base.s1 = derived.s1;
>   base.s2 = derived.s2;
>   ...
>   base.s100 = derived.s100;

Not really. As mentioned in the first comment by Danh.

```
base = derived
```

is enough, since it performs implicit dynamic upcast (i.e. converting from pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base). See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/